# About omics journals

Tags: research-process, thesis

Help me please. Omics group want fee to withdraw my accepted article. If I dont pay any fee, will they blockade my accepted article.I am waiting your response immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Omics is a disreputable publisher.  Your best option is to ignore them.  Never give them money.

Comment: I never gave them money but I wonder if they blockade my accepted article.please help me

Comment: Ignore them.  They have no power.  They want to trick you into giving them money.

Comment: If I send my article which has been accepted in omics group to another journal, is it possibile.